# How to determine the cause for "BUS-Error"

Tags: python, linux, embedded

I'm working on a variscite board with a yocto distribution and python 2.7.3.

I get sometimes a **Bus error** message from the python interpreter.
My program runs normally at least some hours or days before the error ocours.
But when I get it once, I get it directly when I try to restart my program.
I have to reboot before the system works again.

My program uses only a serial port, a bit usb communication and some tcp sockets.

I can switch to another hardware and get the same problems.

I also used the python selftest with
`python -c "from test import testall"`

And I get errors for these two tests

> test_getattr (test.test_builtin.BuiltinTest) ... ERROR test_nameprep
>   (test.test_codecs.NameprepTest) ... ERROR

And the selftest stops always at

> test_callback_register_double (ctypes.test.test_callbacks.SampleCallbacksTestCase) ... Segmentation
>   fault

But when the systems runs some hours the selftests stops earlier at

> ctypes.macholib.dyld
>   Bus error

I checked the RAM with memtester, it seems to be okay.
How I can find the cause for the problems?

Comment: memtester was a good idea, but you may want to check kernel messages (`dmesg`). Last (and first) time I get a "bus error" a couple of weeks ago was while running some git commands, but it may have been anything since the root cause was clearly my hard drive dying as kernel traces showed, so I'd say this may be your flash as well.

Comment: Usually a bus error on modern systems running linux come from attempting to perform unaligned memory access. Which *usually* happens when a C programmer thinks they're being clever by casting some arbitrary pointer to a larger than `char` type, e.g. being lazy about serializing/deserializing to/from a file or socket read/write buffer.  Is your entire program actually written in Python, or is Python just being used as a test framework?  Can you just attach a debugger to the process and backtrace when you hit the bus error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bus errors are generally caused by applications trying to access memory that hardware cannot physically address. In your case there is a segmentation fault which may cause dereferencing a bad pointer or something similar which leads to accessing a memory address which physically is not addressable. I'd start by root causing the segmentation fault first as the bus error is the secondary symptom.

Answer (score 4):

A year later I found the indirect cause for the problems.

I wrote a crc16 module which used:

```
from ctypes import c_ushort
...
value = c_ushort(crcValue >>8 ) ...
```

In case of a BUS-Error this was the problematic part.

I don't assume that the c_ushort() function itself causes the problem, it's only the function which shows that there is something broken.

The problem gone after upgrading the system to `Linux version 3.14.38-6QP+g8740b9f (test@Yocto) (gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC) )`