# How to debug a QString causing a bus error?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with my Qt code on it (Qt 5.12.5). When I run my code, it randomly crashes with a Bus Error after a few hours. I am not sure how to work out the exact cause. I cross compile on Ubuntu for the RPi using the latest Raspberry Pi OS (2020-05-27).

The core dump (I have replaced some irrelevant parts with ...)

```js
pi@raspberrypi: $ gdb TEST core
GNU gdb (Raspbian 8.2.1-2) 8.2.1
...
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from TEST...done.
[New LWP 1233]
...
[New LWP 1226]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./TEST'.
Program terminated with signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
#0  0x755b5b7c in QString::arg(long long, int, int, QChar) const () from /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x6feff440 (LWP 1233))]
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x755b5b7c in QString::arg(long long, int, int, QChar) const () at /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#1  0x0001c0bc in QString::arg(int, int, int, QChar) const (this=0x6fefdc78, a=12, fieldWidth=0, base=10, fillChar=...) at ../raspi/qt5pi/include/QtCore/qstring.h:976
#2  0x00039ff8 in StageState::getStateString() (this=0x6fefdf00) at ../TEST/stage.h:35

...

#7  0x00142124 in TEST::timerExpired() (this=0x7ecd4708) at ../TEST/TEST.cpp:51
        __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = "void TEST::timerExpired()"
        locker = {val = 2127384345}
#8  0x0015c188 in TEST::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**) (_o=0x7ecd4708, _c=QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod, _id=2, _a=0x6fefe9d8) at moc_TEST.cpp:122
        _t = 0x7ecd4708
#9  0x75722b08 in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) () at /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#10 0x75730c1c in QTimer::timeout(QTimer::QPrivateSignal) () at /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#11 0x75730fc8 in QTimer::timerEvent(QTimerEvent*) () at /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#12 0x75724194 in QObject::event(QEvent*) () at /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#13 0x768c6b88 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () at /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#14 0x768ce29c in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () at /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#15 0x759b62ec in QCoreApplication::self () at /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
(gdb)
```

../TEST/stage.h:35 refers to this code:
`return QString("text %1").arg(aInt);`

Possible causes and fixes I am considering:

To me, from the stack trace, it looks like the crashes are occurring inside QString, possibly due to a Qt bug? However I am not sure. I can try a newer version of Qt.

I am also using a QTimer in a thread, maybe this could cause a issue, accessing a object from other threads? I am already using QMutex. I could instead only use the gui thread short term and test if crashes still occur.

Searching online, I found a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970110/how-to-determine-the-cause-for-bus-error#comment61507328_36970110) to look a the dmesg output (below), maybe my MicroSD card is dying? I am waiting for a new one to arrive.

Anything else?

```js
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dmesg
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.44-v7+ (dom@buildbot) (gcc version 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-88-g8460611)) #1320 SMP Wed Jun 3 16:07:06 BST 2020
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fd034] revision 4 (ARMv7), cr=10c5383d

...

[   17.898294] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   17.898313] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[16092.809350] Alignment trap: not handling instruction e1903f9f at [<755b5b78>]
[16092.809367] 8<--- cut here ---
[16092.815191] Unhandled fault: alignment exception (0x001) at 0x6f577277
[16092.820865] pgd = 6aa8fcbe
[16092.826468] [6f577277] *pgd=3278c835, *pte=2812175f, *ppte=28121c7f
```

Here is another bus error that is similar but not quite the same as previously:

```js
pi@raspberrypi:~/TEST/bin $ gdb TEST core
GNU gdb (Raspbian 8.2.1-2) 8.2.1
...
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from TEST...done.
[New LWP 767]
...
[New LWP 763]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./TEST'.
Program terminated with signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
#0  0x7568d470 in QString::fromAscii_helper(char const*, int) () from /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x709bf440 (LWP 767))]
(gdb) bt
#0  0x7568d470 in QString::fromAscii_helper(char const*, int) () at /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#1  0x75830da4 in  () at /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#2  0x0001c030 in QString::QString(char const*) (this=0x709be71c, ch=0x15fa88 "[0-9| ]{3}") at ../raspi/qt5pi/include/QtCore/qstring.h:700
#3  0x00029da8 in Measurement::doesRececivedDataFormatMatchRegex(QString) (this=0x709be7f4, receivedData=...) at ../TEST/Measurement.h:103

...


#12 0x7580c58c in QSocketNotifier::activated(int, QSocketNotifier::QPrivateSignal) () at /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#13 0x7580c90c in QSocketNotifier::event(QEvent*) () at /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#14 0x769a2b88 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () at /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#15 0x769aa29c in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () at /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#16 0x75a922ec in QCoreApplication::self () at /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
```

Edit: added getStateString() and doesRececivedDataFormatMatchRegex() functions

```
QString getStateString() {
    switch (state) {
    case StageState::AEnum:
            return QString("text %1").arg(aInt);
...
    default:
         return QString("Unknown");
    }
}
```

```
bool Measurement::doesRececivedDataFormatMatchRegex(QString receivedData)
{
    QRegExp regExp("[0-9| ]{3}");

    return receivedData.indexOf(regExp) != -1;
}
```

Comment: What do `StageState::getStateString()` and `Measurement::doesRececivedDataFormatMatchRegex()` functions do? Can you show the code?

Comment: I have edited the question adding those two functions.