Im getting this error "fatal Python error: Bus error"
I have a test script for which I'm using selenium along with pytest. Sometimes I get an error saying 'fatal Python erorr: Bus error'. I'm not using sockets, threads or anything else that requires use of memory allocation and even pointers. I've attached screenshots for reference.
I'm also using jpype so that I can use extent report for reporting purposes and the first line in the screenshot that is giving the error in the conftest.py in fin is as follows:
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def report_util(request):
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
    extent = ExtentReports()
    if not os.path.exists("../reports/"):
        os.makedirs("../reports/")
    extent_reporter = ExtentSparkReporter(f'../reports/report_{timestamp}.html')
    extent_reporter.config().thumbnailForBase64(True)
    extent_reporter.config().setCss("img {width: 400px;}")
    extent.attachReporter(extent_reporter)

    def fin():
        try:
            extent.flush()
            jp.shutdownJVM()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Exception during teardown: {e}")
            raise

    request.session.addfinalizer(fin)

    return extent


I tried mprof to see if there are any memory leaks... but the error doesn't happen always. So its quite hard to find the issue as when I was trying to do memory profiling I didn't got the same error.

some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970110/how-to-determine-the-cause-for-bus-error

by look of it you somehow broke call stack

I don't have any recursive functions. is it still possible to break the call stack?

In native code? Yes, easily. Aside of our namesake something may go out of bounds and damage returnaddress or stack underflow may happen. The source is in library you're using, It can be even their bug, exposed by your or something caused by your use-case.
